# Excel column-like chart

Tags: excel

I need a chart like this but can not find how to make it in excel or word. [image: img]

I tried making a column chart and reduce the width but it's anyway too fat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly more work, but here is a workaround. Basically, you want to create separate `scatter` plots connected by `line` for each data point. That way first point will be on the x-axis (where y is 0) and another point will higher up depending on the actual value you want to plot. In the attached figure, the actual data to be plotted is under `y2` (Column `E`). You will have to create `x1` and `x2` (under Column `B` and `C`) to specify spacing of different lines. Then, you will have to import each data point separately (Example for importing `Label A` is in the figure) and define line color, width etc. Also, set `Marker` to `None` for each plot.

[image]